# I thought that I could increment the value of a hash key in ruby. Why is this failing?

Tags: ruby

> hash =  {     "bill" => '39',     'kim' => '35',  'larry' => '47' }
>
> for word in hash      hash[word] += 1 end
>
> puts "Bill is now #{hash['bill]']}"

This is the error message

> undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't working because `word` is going to represent an array for each key/value pair in the hash.  So, on the first pass through the loop, `word` is going to be `["bill", "39"]`.  That's why `hash[word]` is returning `nil`.

Illustrated:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > for word in hash
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002?>   puts word.inspect
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003?> end
["bill", 40]
["kim", 36]
["larry", 48]
```

What you probably want is:

```
hash.keys.each do |k|
  hash[k] += 1
end
```

The second problem is that you're storing the values as Strings instead of Ints.  So, the += 1 operation will fail.  Either change your hash to this:

```
hash = { "bill" => 39, 'kim' => 35, 'larry' => 47 }
```

Or convert the value to an integer before doing the + 1.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify 2 variables for a hash in the for in loop:

```
hash = { "bill" => 39, 'kim' => 35, 'larry' => 47 }

for word, key in hash 
  hash[word] += 1 
end

puts "Bill is now #{hash['bill]'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the *native* `each` enumerator instead:

```
friend_ages = { 'Bill' => 39, 'Kim' => 35, 'Larry' => 47 }
friend_ages.each { |name, age| friend_ages[name] += 1 }

puts "Bill is now #{friend_ages['Bill']}."
```